# How to always append an ampersand for certain commands? (MacOS / bash)

Tags: bash, command-line, macos-sierra

Whenever I open emacs, I always want to run it in the background. How can I make it so that whenever I type "emacs xyz" the shell automatically runs "emacs xyz &"?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Define a shell function that does what you want, and put it into your `.bashrc`.

Comment: I wouldn't describe this as "appending an ampersand", but as ensuring that your command is run in the background. When you talk about appending, that has implications about how it interacts with other syntax that don't really hold up (just as how an alias, doing string *prefixing*, can change how code is parsed, something that truly appended a string would be able to modify parse-time behavior, and that's not really an element of what you're looking for).

Comment: To demonstrate what I meant above: `alias redefine-foo{='foo() { '` actually makes `redefine-foo{ echo bar; }` parse as `foo() { echo bar; }`: It's string substitution that takes place *before* any parsing happens. By contrast, sane answers to your question will generally involve creating a command or wrapper that controls what it does *after* being parsed in such a way as to run your desired command in the background.

Comment: @John1024 cross-posted link now dead :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following shell function (which can be put in `.bashrc`) does what you're asking for:

```
emacs() { command emacs "$@" & }
```

`command` ensures that the real (external) `emacs` command is invoked, rather than having the function call itself recursively. `"$@"` expands to the list of arguments, ensuring that they're passed through.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a simple bash script named whatever you like, let's say `emax` in this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
emacs "$@" &
```

And then invoke as `emax xyz`

Comment: This wound up working for me. I then aliased "emacs" to "emax." Thanks!

Comment: You could also have the script invoke `/usr/bin/emacs` or have a line like `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin` after the shebang -- at which point it could be named `emacs` itself, so long as it's installed in a place that's before the real binary in your PATH. An alias is less than ideal -- it doesn't work in as many places as an exported function or a script will. (John's answer here will work even with `find ... -exec emax {} +`, or `-exec emacs` if, of course, you name the shim `emacs`; `find -exec` doesn't recognise aliases at all).