# Always append arguments to command in Powershell

Tags: powershell, arguments

There's a few commands I need to run repetitively in Powershell, with some variable arguments in content and length, but some arguments must always be there. I don't want to forget those arguments, so is there a way to create a function that does this?

I have tried using things like `Invoke-Expression`, but when I use brackets in a command, Powershell thinks it's a type and tells me my cast is not valid. If I escape the argument list and provide an argument in the form `Key=Value`, PowerShell parses it into a `System.Object[]` and the command fails. I figured it might be better not to ask about how to fix that, but how to solve my root problem.

You can consider this a somewhat duplicate of [How to always append an ampersand for certain commands? (MacOS / bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594693/how-to-always-append-an-ampersand-for-certain-commands-macos-bash) but for PowerShell.

Comment: Try adding code sample of what you're actually tryhing to do? I assume the commands you're trying to append aren't PS commands but its not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own version of the command as a Function with mandatory parameters:

```
Function RunMyCommand {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)][string]$Argument1,
        [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)][int]$Argument2,
        [Parameter(Position=2,mandatory=$true)]$Argument3
    )
    # Amend this according to the syntax and string manipulation required for your command
    ThisIsMyCommand $Argument1 $Argument2 $Argument3
}

RunMyCommand -Argument1 ThisString -Argument2 ThisNumber -Argument3 ThisAnything
```